# set a new adapter in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Initially I am having a adapter for recyclerView like this -

```
pAdapter = new PSCListWrapAdapter(getContext(),data);
recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
```

after button click I want to change the adapter of recyclerView with another adapter as -

```
sAdapter = new SellerInSearchAdapter(sList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.invalidate();
```

after setting new adapter the recyclerView got blank, no items are displayed but when I open soft keyboard, items comes up, what is going on and how to do it correctly ?

Comment: Why are you using two separate adapter ? Use only one adapter and when you press button clear older list and fill with new data in adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @MD because models of data are different

Comment: Try removing recyclerView.invalidate();

Comment: models of data can be different even if you only have one adapter. You can set the data type you adapter adopt to `Object` in Java or `Any` in Kotlin, then the adapter can accept both type of data model before and after

Comment: RecyclerView is designed to fit this situaction, it's totally fine to have multi-type data in one recyclerview.

Comment: @AgentP I have tried already but no effect

Comment: @Anthonyeef I mean to say data is different type also the item layout is totally different, so I make separate models and separate adapter.

Comment: I think we might be missing some code here Is it possible to post entire code ?

Comment: @AgentP tell me what code you want, there is so much to post.

Comment: "item layout is totally different" --> that's also not a problem to you. You can have recyclerview adapter with different data type, and each type corespond to its own viewholder.

Comment: https://github.com/drakeet/MultiType I suggest you take a look at this github repo. it demostrates a way to render different kind of item layout with different type of data model. You can do the same thing with valina recyclerview adapter and some custom view holder easily.

Comment: @Anthonyeef are you saying I should first check what type of data it is and then inflate layout accordingly ? and also check and put the data ?

Comment: the process, "first check the type of data then inflate layout accordingly" is exactly recyclerview adapter's job. You can have different recyclerview viewholder inside one recyclerview adapter, and the adapter can do the job for you. Checkout some google's demo or the repo I post above then you can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting any `adapter` to `recycler view`,  you have to set the `layout manager`

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
        = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and then set the adapter to `recyclerview`

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

Comment: of course I set these things I am getting empty rV when I change the adapter, this is not I asked.